# Typehints/mypy in configuration class abstraction of dict

Tags: python, configuration, mypy, python-typing, abstraction

I have a `config.yaml` in which various parameters of my program can be specified, that is heterogeneous in terms of types:

```
attr1: some_string
attr2: some_int
attr3:
  subkey1: some_string
  subkey2: some_string
attr4:
  - item1
  - item2
```

To hide the configuration file from the rest of the code, I use a class that mostly just passes the values from the dict to the code.

```
class Config:

    def __init__(self):
        with open("config.yaml", "r") as f:
            self.config_dict: dict[str, Any] = yaml.safe_load(f)

    @property
    def attr1(self) -> str:
        return self.config_dict["attr1"]

    @property
    def attr2(self) -> int:
        return self.config_dict["attr2"]

    ...
```

mypy now complains about the types returned by the class properties.

```
 error: Returning Any from function declared to return "str"
 error: Returning Any from function declared to return "int"
```

What are the best practices I should follow here to use typing correctly? Are assertions of the type of the user provided attribute values the way to go?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using something like [`pydantic`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/), possibly [`pydantic-settings`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/pydantic_settings/) instead? It seems to fit your goal pretty well and solves the type-safety issue much more cleanly.

Comment: If you do not want to use additional libraries, I would suggest using the built-in [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) instead.

Comment: If you have your own validation logic somewhere, then [`TypedDict`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/) is much more lightweight - it''s really just a heterogeneous dictionary with fixed keys, not opaque or type checkers.